# Importing Scala TreeSet

Tags: scala

I have a question about how to import Scala's TreeSet.

When I write (in a worksheet)

```
  val myOrdering = Ordering.fromLessThan[Int](_ < _)
                                              //> myOrdering  : scala.math.Ordering[Int] = scala.math.Ordering$$anon$9@4947
                                              //| c4ee
  val myTreeSet = scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet.empty(myOrdering)
                                              //> sortedSet  : scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet[Int] = TreeSet()
```

everything is fine.  But when I write

```
  import scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet._
  ...
  val myTreeSet = TreeSet.empty(myOrdering)
```

I get an error: not found: value TreeSet. So the question is how to import TreeSet.

Thanks.

Comment: just remove last two characters from "import scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet._"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet._` imports the *members* of `TreeSet`, but `TreeSet` is not a member of itself. You should write simply `import scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet`.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet
```

You are currently pulling everything inside of `TreeSet`.

Or you can do this:

```
import scala.collection.immutable._
```